# Readline support when running programs in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, jline

I've just started using JLine for console input in my programs. In a bash shell, this works great. In the Eclipse Console view, nothing useful works - no history, no command completion.

Is there a way to get this working? (I'm on OSX in case that's relevant).

Note: I've looked at the Local Terminal plugin (https://code.google.com/p/elt/) and the TM Terminal (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) but these both seem to be about running a general terminal, rather being used as a terminal for the programs I'm running. However, I may be missing something.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't provide a full terminal, so you don't get standard features like tab completion, etc.  It also [doesn't support the Java `Console` class](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429), if that's what JLine uses.

Comment: Yup - just trying to figure out if there was any way around that.